# Can't get correct dynamically added divs count

Tags: javascript, html

I have a body element, and in this body element I have a child element with id `fullpage`. And this element contains child element with classname `section`. In function `load_works()` I add two more `section` elements

```
<body>

    <div id="fullpage">

        <div class="section">
              <!-- Content -->
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        load_works();
    </script>


</body>
```

Contents of main.js:

```
function load_works() {

    var container = document.getElementById('fullpage');

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var new_section = document.createElement('div');
            new_section.className = "section";

            container.appendChild(new_section);
        }

}
```

The problem is, that when I try to count `section` elements with `getElementsByClassName()` like this after `load_works()` is executed

```
function some_function() {

     var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
     console.log(sections.length);

}
```

it always returns 1, and this, I think, is because I have only one static `section` element. `querySelectorAll()` of course and other `get-` fucntions also aren't working. So, how can I achieve the correct result with pure Javascript, not jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better should place all javascript inside one file like `main.js` and then you only need to call `some_function()` after `load_works()`.

```js
function load_works() {
  var container = document.getElementById('fullpage');
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var new_section = document.createElement('div');
    new_section.className = "section";
    container.appendChild(new_section);
  }
}

function some_function() {
  var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('section');
  alert(sections.length);
}

load_works();
some_function();
```

```html
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
```